# Trouble with anonymous method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, anonymous-types

I have a method that excepts an `IEnumerable<T>` and a lambda expression that describes the field to be used to compare a linq-to-sql collection to an array. The method returns the matching records.

```
public IEnumerable<ZipCode> match<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, 
        Func<ZipCode, T> matchPhrase) {
    return (from zipCode in _table
            where values.Contains<T>(matchPhrase)
            select zipCode).Distinct();
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Argument type `'Func<ZipCode, T>'` is not assignable to parameter type `'T'`

The method would be called like so (where `values` is an `IEnumerable<string>` and `x.zipcode` is a `string`):

```
var zipCodes = _zipCodeRepository.match(values, x => x.zipcode)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on John's suggestion of using `HashSet<T>` I have changed my code however I'm getting a different error now

> Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

I think I may not have been clear on my question and I think I'm using the wrong method signature to get my desired outcome. Let me explain with a more simple code example:

```
public IEnumerable<ZipCode> match(IEnumerable<string> values) {
    return (from zipCode in _table
            where values.Contains(zipCode.zipcode)
            select zipCode).Distinct();
}
```

I am tyring to accomplish this but with anonymous types. I would like to pass in the field to be used in the `Contains()` via a lambda. So `zipCode.zipcode` would be passed into the method as the second argument: `x => x.zipcode`

Comment: You almost certainly want to put `values` into a `HashSet` right at the start so that you can more effectively search it.  As it is you're enumerating `values`, doing a linear search, for each item in `_table`.  This is both very inefficient, and also iterating the enumerable many times, which really should be avoided in a function like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you wanted to *call* the delegate:

```
return (from zipCode in _table
        where values.Contains(matchPhrase(zipCode))
        select zipCode).Distinct();
```

Mind you, that would potentially be very expensive. You might want to create a set first:

```
HashSet<T> valueSet = new HashSet<T>(values);
return _table.Where(x => valueSet.Contains(matchPhrase(x))
             .Distinct();
```

(I've removed the query expression here as it was doing more harm than good in terms of readability.)

Comment: @bflemi3 I was about to suggest you not name the argument to the function the same as the method itself...it could cause confusion.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why using a _HashSet_ and then use _Where_ and _Contains_ while the LINQ join method perfectly do this task in a more performant way?

Comment: @CédricBignon: What makes you think a join is more performant? That's basically what the join would do internally. The join is a fine solution, but I don't think it would perform any better.

Comment: @bflemi3: That's what you get for not only not using the right name in the original version of your code, but also forcing sideways scrolling - it's better to format code to avoid scrolling where possible. I've updated it now, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, I've changed to get rid of the horizontal scrolling. I've also updated my question. I don't think I was clear enough and I my be misunderstanding exactly what method signature I should be using.

Comment: @bflemi3: It's unclear where *either* DynamicInvoke *or* SQL come into this. Are you trying to execute this in the database? If so, you should be using `IQueryable<T>` and expression trees instead - and it'll get a bit more complicated.

Comment: @JonSkeet To be honest, I would think my simplified version would be done in the database, and it was working before I refactored it, but I'm not sure if linq-to-sql would query the db then do the `Contains()` in memory or not. My goal was just to refactor so that this method could be used for any number of types. This is my inexperience showing :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I was totally focused on the _IEnumerable.Contains_ version. Then what advantage provide your method over the join method?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `(zipCode)` in `Contains`

```
public IEnumerable<ZipCode> match<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, Func<ZipCode, T> matchPhrase) {
    return (from zipCode in _table
            where values.Contains(matchPhrase(zipCode))  // <- Here (and you don't need to specify <T>, the compiler deduce it from the argument)
            select zipCode).Distinct();
}
```

You can use a Join method to have better performance (complexity in `O(n)`):

```
public IEnumerable<ZipCode> match<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, Func<ZipCode, T> matchPhrase)
{
    return (from zipCode in _table
            join value in values on matchPhrase(zipCode) equals value
            select zipCode).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: `match` *is* a function, and contains doesn't accept a function at all.

Comment: @bflemi3 Take a look at the join "version" of your method. It reduces the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Contains only accepts a string as argument, not an Expression. You won't be able to parametrize it on this level.

You could pass in the whole where part as parameter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             var values = new List<string>();
             values.Add("123");

             Console.WriteLine(
                 Match(zip => values.Contains(zip.Code)).Count()); // -> 1

             Console.WriteLine(
                 Match(zip => values.Contains(zip.OtherCode)).Count()); // -> 0

             Console.Read();
         }

         public static IEnumerable<ZipCode> Match(Expression<Func<ZipCode, bool>> predicate)
         {
             var table = new List<ZipCode> 
                      { new ZipCode { Code = "123" }, new ZipCode { OtherCode = "234" } }
                .AsQueryable();

             return (from zipCode in table.Where(predicate)
                    select zipCode).Distinct();
         }
     }
     public class ZipCode
     {
         public string Code { get; set; }

         public string OtherCode { get; set; }
     }
}
```